# Swift: Run Timer in Background and send Notifications

Tags: swift, timer, apple-push-notifications, background-process

I know there are already questions about that topic but it doesn't work for me so I want to ask the question again.

What I am trying to do:

I have a simple Interval Timer App where you can set your interval and your break. When the user close the App(not complete, just swiped up to go the home screen) he should get messages when the interval or the break begin again. I already tried two different way.

1.
I integrated Background Modes and write and function that notify the user. The function is called in the timer when the interval/break starts.

```
func notify(title: String, message: String){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = message
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    
    let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MSG", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(req, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

The code perfectly execute on the simulator. The timer runs in the background and the Notifications are send to the user. However, when I run the code on an actual device the timer stops running and so the notifications aren't send. I read that it isn't possible to run a timer in the background. Is this true or is there a way?

2. When I read that timers don't run in the background I tried another way. When the user leave the app I run a function that will creat notifications for every change that will happen.

   ```
    func notify(trainingsState: [TrainingsState]){

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = trainingsState[0].name
    content.body = trainingsState[0].msg ?? "Error"
    var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: Double(insgesamt), repeats: false)

    var request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "startedExercise", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    var dauerInsgesamt: Double{
        var dauer = 0.0
        for _ in 1...Int(daten.durchgaenge){
            for _ in übungListe.übungen{
                dauer += daten.intervallInsgesamt
                dauer += daten.pauseInsgesamt
            }
            dauer -= daten.pauseInsgesamt
            dauer += daten.pauseZwischenDurchgängenInsgesamt
        }

        print(dauer)
        return dauer
    }

    var dauerBisGroßePause: Double{
        var dauer = 0.0
        for _ in übungListe.übungen{
            dauer += daten.intervallInsgesamt
            dauer += daten.pauseInsgesamt
        }
        dauer -= daten.pauseInsgesamt

        print(dauer)
        return dauer
    }

    for übung in trainingsState{
        content.title = übung.name
        content.body = übung.msg ?? ""

        if !übung.isSpecial{
            trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: übung.isBreak ? daten.pauseInsgesamt : daten.intervallInsgesamt, repeats: true)
        }else{
            if übung.dauer == nil{
                trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: dauerBisGroßePause, repeats: true)
            }else{
                trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: dauerInsgesamt, repeats: false)
            }
        }

        request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: übung.id.uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }

But this don't work. I get the error that the timeInterval of the trigger have to be at least 60 seconds but the user also have to get notifications when the interval is only 30 seconds long. Does anyone know how to fix that issue?

**Conclusion:**
I know that it is possible to program the behavior I want because there are apps which do exactly what I am trying to do. The question: How can I send notifications to the user when the pause or interval will begin when the app is in the background.

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

Timers get invalidated when the app is suspended or terminated. You can use **background modes** to awake the app to perform a certain task (you get 30 seconds to finish it in the background).

Here is some material from 2019, there is a link to 2020 also: [Advances in App Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707)